# How to scrape the ratings and all the reviews from the website using selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape the rating and all the reviews on the page .But not able to find the path .

```
enter code here
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import time
chrome_path =r'C:/Users/91940/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.lazada.sg/products/samsung-galaxy-watch3-bt-45mm-titanium-i1156462257- 
        s4537770883.html?search=1&freeshipping=1")
product_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="module_product_title_1"]/div/div/h1')
print(product_name.text)
rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='score-average']")
print(rate.text)
review = driver .find_element_by_xpath('//* 
         [@id="module_product_review"]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]')
print(review.text)
```

Comment: just the page 1 reviews?

Comment: No i need for all pagination

Comment: QHarr ! Can you please review this question :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68177444/when-scraping-all-the-div-to-get-the-data-getting-the-null-list-using-lxml-in-py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `print(product_name.text)` is getting execute correct, right ?

There is an issue with `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='score-average']")` I could not found `score-average` anywhere in HTML source.

so try this instead :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.pdp-review-summary")
print(rate.text)
```

You can try the below code to get **review** :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.lazada.sg/products/samsung-galaxy-watch3-bt-45mm-titanium-i1156462257- s4537770883.html?search=1&freeshipping=1")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class$='pdp-review-summary__link']"))).click()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[contains(text(), 'Ratings & Reviews')]")))).perform()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.item-content")))
for review in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.item-content"):
    print(review.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: and how to locate to get the reviews from that website

Comment: where is review located in the website ? Do I have to click on Ratings ?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name("mod-reviews")     and to locate the specification for driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="module_product_detail"]/div/div/div/div[2] ')

Comment: it gives me error as  "No such element unable to locate the element".

Comment: Well in that case you'd have to scroll till end of web page using Selenium

Comment: but how to locate it , to get  the reviews

Comment: You will have to click on `Ratings` first.. that will scroll bit and write this line after that `driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")` and then use the find_elements from my answer.

Comment: Can yo also look for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67955673/want-to-get-the-text-from-the-li-tag-using-selenium

Comment: I am getting the error by trying above mention code : Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="pdp-link pdp-link_size_s pdp-link_theme_blue pdp-review-summary__link">...</a> is not clickable at point (454, 6).

Comment: Can you please review this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68177444/when-scraping-all-the-div-to-get-the-data-getting-the-null-list-using-lxml-in-py

Comment: @P.D  :Sure, I will. it will take some time

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a problem with your path? (apologies I'm not on windows to test). From memory, Windows paths use `\` characters instead of `/`. Additionally, you may need two backticks after the drive path (`C:\\`).

`c:\\Users\91940\AppData\Local\...`

Comment: No there is no issue at that level . I am just not able to scrape the reviews .Kindly suggest how to used search the reviews and get the text

Comment: Apologies, I would recommend trying to write more descriptive questions just so that it is clear what the core problem and what you have tried to solve it. It helps us better understand what the problem is and we can help you :)