# Want to get the text from the li tag using selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want the text from the li tag that is the specification of the product but when i am searching using `driver.find_element_by_css_selector`   it gives the error as path cannot find .So not able to get the text .

```
enter code here
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import time
chrome_path =r'C:/Users/91940/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.lazada.sg/products/samsung-galaxy-watch3-bt-45mm-titanium- 
  i1156462257-s4537770883.html?search=1&freeshipping=1")
speci = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('data-spm-anchor- 
          id="a2o42.pdp_revamp.product_detail.i17.5fa031ceGZk42Z"')
```

how to get the text from the li tag .When I run the above code it gives the error "No such element unable to locate the element".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are anti-scraping measures. If those do not affect you then you can use css classes to target the li elements to loop over, and the title/values for each specification:

```
specs = [(i.find_element_by_css_selector('.key-title').text, i.find_element_by_css_selector('.key-value').text) for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.key-li')]
```

---

You can also regex that required info from a `script tag` and just use `requests` and `json` to parse out the spec (there is other info including reviews included in `data`)

```
import re, json

r = requests.get("https://www.lazada.sg/products/samsung-galaxy-watch3-bt-45mm-titanium-i1156462257-s4537770883.html?search=1&freeshipping=1",
                 headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = r.text
#html = driver.page_source

data = json.loads(re.search(r'var __moduleData__ = (.*);', html).group(1))
print(data['data']['root']['fields']['specifications'])
```

Comment: Can you please look into the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67954661/how-to-scrape-the-ratings-and-all-the-reviews-from-the-website-using-selenium/67955842#67955842