# When scraping all the div to get the data getting the null list using lxml in python

Tags: python, lxml

I want to scrape the product title , product link , product price but when I am using the xpath it is showing the null list . How  to add the xpath and for loop to get the above details . I have tried  this

```
import requests
import lxml.html

html =  requests.get("https://www.lazada.sg/catalog/? 
      q=Samsung+Mobile&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=a2o42.home.search.go.654346b52P3y8Y")
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)
#print(doc)

new = doc.xpath('//div[@class ="index__box___1Ffv-"]')
print(len(new))
for node in new:

   title = node.xpath('//* 
        [@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()')
   print(len(title))
   print(title)
```

I need to get all the product details as mention above. I want this by using only lxml library.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you are running into is that the information you want is not in `doc`. To see what you're working with, try something like:

```
f = open('title_dump.html', 'wb')
f.write(html.content)
```

Open it in a browser or text editor, and you'll notice that titles, prices and so on are missing. Most likely, they are being filled in by Javascript. As such, this may not be possible using only lxml.

Comment: Ok . Can we scrape it from the API  ?

Comment: If they have an API, that would probably be a much better solution.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to scrape from the API

Comment: Can you please suggest for this question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72513224/data-scraping-of-the-numbers-and-details-from-the-website